# Probability of successful transmission

Tags: probability

Preamble: Device $A$ transmits to another device $B$ (in the same system say System $1$) either through any relay node $R$ (in system $2$) in the shaded area $S$ or directly. The probability that $R$ exists within the area $S$ is $P_{re}$. In other words, the probability that $R$ does not exist within $S$ is $1-P_{re}$. Let the density of devices in system $1$ be $\lambda_1$ and that in in system $2$ be $\lambda_2$. Given that for $A$ to transmit to $R$, the density of active transmitters in $A$ and $R$ is $\frac{\lambda_1}{2}P_{re}$.

Question:
I really do not understand how the probability of successful transmission in the case given in the picture below is gotten (Specifically in equations (15) to (17)).

[image]

In my humble opinion, I think with this information given, the equations should look as shown below.
\begin{equation*} \begin{split} & \text{Pr}(SIR_{D2D,2}\geq T_{1})\\ & =e^{-C_{\alpha}T_{1}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}R^{2}\left[\lambda_{0}\left(\frac{P_{0}}{p_{1}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\lambda_{1}\left(1-P_{re}\right) \right]}. \end{split} \tag{15} \end{equation*}

\begin{align*} & \text{Pr}(SIR_{D2RN,2}\geq T_{2})\notag\\ & =e^{-C_{\alpha}T_{2}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}A^{2}R^{2}\left\{\lambda_{0}\left(\frac{P_{0}}{P_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\frac{\lambda_{1}}{2}{P_{re}}\left(\frac{P_{1}}{P_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\frac{\lambda_{1}}{2}{P_{re}}\right\}},\tag{16}\\ & \text{Pr}(SIR_{RN2D,2}\geq T_{1})\notag\\ & =e^{-C_{\alpha}T_{1}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}A^{2}R^{2}\left\{\lambda_{0}\left(\frac{P_{0}}{P_{1}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{1}{P_{re}}+\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{1}{P_{re}}\left(\frac{P_{2}}{P_{1}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\right\}}.\tag{17} \end{align*}

Am I wrong?

Comment: How does this relate to your other question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848449/probability-and-density-transmission-problem

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This question presents the overall scenario and my take at it. Since I do not have a definite reference I need to ask on this platform. The second question specifically narrows this down to an aspect in this scenario where seems most unclear to me. A detailed answer to that question would shape the answer to this one.