# Probability and density transmission problem

Tags: probability

Two devices in System $1$ could communicate either directly or using a relay in System $2$. Given System 1 has a density of $\lambda_1$ and System 2 has density $\lambda_2$. The probability that a relay exists between these two devices is $P_{re}$. Whenever they communicate using the relay, only $\frac{1}{2}P_{re}\lambda_1$ of the devices in System 1 can transmit to System 2. Similarly, $\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1P_{re}$ of the devices in System 2 can receive (The density of transmit and receive pair should be equal). What is the density of transmitters that would transmit directly i.e mutual transmission between devices in System 1?

I have two likely outcomes, but it is not really clear to me which is most correct.

Firstly, one could say that since there are a total of $\lambda_1$ devices, since $\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1P_{re}$ can transmit using a relay,  it means $\lambda_1-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1P_{re}$ can transmit directly.

On the other hand, one could say that the probability that a relay does not exist is $1-P_{re}$. The event that a relay doesn't exist and devices in System 1 transmit without the relay reduces its density to  $\lambda_1\big(1-P_{re}\big)$.

Which of these two is more accurate?

Comment: What's the density of a system?

Comment: Also, after saying "whenever they communicate using the relay", the number of devices in system 1 that can transmits to system 2 is a conditional one, i.e. conditional propbability should be involved. Thus the appearance of $p_{re}$ in the conditional probability is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Density of which system?

Comment: Above all, the probablistic setup in the description is too vague to be understood. Could you use standard concepts such as events and (conditional) probability to rigorously define the whole setup? That's also why I haven't yet answered the other bounty question of you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80184/discussion-between-abdulhameed-and-alex-francisco).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Lets say the density of a system, refers to the number of devices in a system. The word system can be imagined as a set of balls of a particular colour in a large container. System 1 is a set of blue balls with a total of $\lambda_1$, System 2 is a set of red balls with a total of $\lambda_2$. These two colours exist together within a large container. Assume we would like to pair the blue balls. Now we have two options, we could pair the balls directly (when the balls are close to each other), or pair them using a red ball in-between to literarily "connect" them.

Comment: The probability that a red ball exist in-between is $P_{re}$. Whenever the red balls are used to connect only fraction $\frac{1}{2}P_{re}\lambda_1$ of the blue balls 1 can "connect" to the red balls. The number of connecting blue balls and receiving red balls must be equal. What is the number of blue balls that can connect to each other without using the red balls?